# using jQuery, I wanted to print table of a provided number, but output is just flashing and goes blank

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new using jQuery. in my 1st program of jQuery, I wanted to print a table of a provided number and its answer is right. but the problem I am facing the output just flashing and goes blank. if I use an alert function, the output stays till I click on "OK".

Here is my code..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get Table</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function funtable_js(){
    $("button").click(function funtable_js(){
        var numm=$("#num").val();
    if(numm!=0)
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
            {
            var tbl=numm*$i;
            var ttbl=$("#out").append("<tr><td>"+tbl+"</td></tr></br>");
            }
            alert("Hello World");
    }
    else
        {
    alert("Wrong Input. Try Again With Valid Number");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="table" method="">
<tr><td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"/><button onClick="funtable_js()"> Get Table </button></td></tr>
<table id="out">

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help... Thank You so much to all.

Comment: You have an ending script tag: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the button is in a form and when the button is clicked the form is getting submitted which refreshes the form.

You can prevent the default action of the click event in the click handler to solve teh problem

```
<button>Get Table</button>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function funtable_js() {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var numm = $("#num").val();
        if (numm != 0) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                var tbl = numm * $i;
                var ttbl = $("#out").append("<tr><td>" + tbl + "</td></tr></br>");
            }
            alert("Hello World");
        } else {
            alert("Wrong Input. Try Again With Valid Number");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kLmmL/1/)

Note: Since you are using a jQuery event handler there is no need to have an `onclick` handler added to the element markup, even if you add it it won't work because the method `funtable_js` is not in the global scope.

---

another solution is to change the type of the button to `button` like

```
<button type="button">Get Table</button>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bGZ9Z/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<input type='button'>` instead of `<button>` tag otherwise form will be submitted to the server each time you perform a button click.

Try This:  [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sudhakar_Tillapudi/5NRCC/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get Table</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (){      
    var numm=$("#num").val();
    if(numm!=0)
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
            {
            var tbl=numm*$i;
            var ttbl=$("#out").append("<tr><td>"+tbl+"</td></tr>");
            }
            //alert("Hello World");
    }
    else
        {
    alert("Wrong Input. Try Again With Valid Number");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="table">
<table><tr><td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"/><input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/></td></tr></table></form>
<table id="out">



</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are not using any submission method on your form because its the `Javascript` that handles your button action. So just delete this two lines on your code:

```
<form name="table" method="">
</form>
```

And edit this line FROM:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"/><button onClick="funtable_js()"> Get Table </button></td></tr>
```

TO:

```
<table><tr><td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"/><button onClick="funtable_js()"> Get Table </button></td></tr></table>
```

Now try your code. It should now work. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with jQuery, it's your HTML is incomplete. The button should be changed to this:

```
<button type="button"> Get Table </button>
```

1. there's no need to add the onclick event because you've added it in the document ready event.
2. button's default behavior is "submit", thus your page refreshes soon after you finished building the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the Form Tag. Your Problem will be solved by then.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get Table</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function funtable_js(){
    $("button").click(function funtable_js(){
        var numm=$("#num").val();
    if(numm!=0)
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
            {
            var tbl=numm*$i;
            var ttbl=$("#out").append("<tr><td>"+tbl+"</td></tr></br>");
            }
            alert("Hello World");
    }
    else
        {
    alert("Wrong Input. Try Again With Valid Number");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<tr><td><input type="text" name="num" id="num"/><button onClick="funtable_js()"> Get Table </button></td></tr>
<table id="out">

</table>
</body>
</html>
```